# dtplyr throws an 'invalid 'type' (closure) of argument' using group_by() %>% sample_n() in dplyr and [[sample()], by=id] in data.table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, dtplyr

I've been using `dtplyr` to speed up an overly complex `dplyr` code, and so far it's been excellent, apart from one issue I can't seem to resolve.

The problem is pretty straight forward to solve in both `dplyr` and `data.table`, but I can't see a way of applying it to a `dtplyr_step` object from `lazy_dt()` without using `collect()` or converting it back to a `data.frame`.

I'm trying to group a dataframe by one column, and sample rows n times based on values in another column.
Here's a working example in `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(id=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d"), 
                 count=sample(1:25, 12, replace=TRUE))

df %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(max(count), replace = TRUE)
```

and in `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(id=c("a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","d","d","d"), 
                 count=sample(1:25, 12, replace=TRUE))

dt[,.SD[sample(.N, max(count,.N), replace=TRUE)],by = id]
```

However, attempting both approaches used on an identical "lazy" `data.table` created  with `lazy_dt()` from the `dtplyr` package:

```
library(dtplyr)

df2 <- lazy_dt(df)

df2 %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(max(count), replace = TRUE)
```

fails with *Error in max(count) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument*

```
df2[,.SD[sample(.N, max(count,.N), replace=TRUE)],by = id]
```

fails with *Error in max(count, .N) : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument*

Presumably because the `count` column is no longer recognised as numeric.

Is there a way of doing this in `dtplyr` **without** converting this back to a data.frame or `data.table` (other than recoding the original `dplyr` code to `data.table` entirely?)

Comment: You could use `slice(sample(n(), max(count), replace = TRUE))`

Comment: Perfect! Add this as an answer?